# How to horizontally images resized (via CSS) to fit a box?

Tags: css, image, responsive-design, centering

I'm currently stuck with this problem. I'm resizing a picture via CSS in a box with its height forced.

```
.img_contener {
width: 100%;
height: 400px;
}
```

There is the CSS for the image resizing :

```
img {  
max-width: 100%;
max-height : auto;
height: auto;
width: auto;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Now I want to center the resultant picture, which, depending on its height, doesn't fit to the containing box, and which is staying by default on the left.

Both the margin:auto and the text-align:center don't work.

I didn't try out jquery solutions so far... I would rather like a CSS-based solution. My alternative is to force-resize the picture using php.

Comment: was the `text-align:center` on your `.img_contener`?

Comment: Do you want to resize picture to fit you container or you want to center it in container?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.img_contener { 
   //your css ...

   overflow:hidden;
}


img {

   //your css ...

   display : block;
   margin : 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your image to be centered in main DIV you need to use a additional tag to img

Something like this

```
<div id="container">

    <p><img src="http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/15767501.jpg" class="inner"/></p>

</div>
```

And Your CSS

```
#container {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.inner {
    height: 120px;
    width: auto;
}

p {
    text-align: center;

}
```

Working Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/TXvuQ/1/

Comment: It is unnecessary to have additional tag to center image inside div

Answer (score 0):

This is completely doable in CSS. Please see my example below, you should also add overflow: hidden to your container object.

HTML

```
<div id="container">

    <img src="http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/15767501.jpg" class="inner"/>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.inner {
    height: 100px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Working Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/TXvuQ/

Answer (score 0):

Margin:auto will only work if you also apply display:block to the image.